# Can Rcpp package DLLs be unloaded without restarting R?

Tags: r, rcpp

When installing a Rcpp package on Windows, you need to ensure that the package DLL is unloaded or you get a "Permission Denied" error when copying the new DLL. This means restarting R on every recompile, which is pretty annoying. Is there any way to unload the package DLL without killing R?

I've tried the `detach("package:my_package", force=TRUE)` command, but it doesnt unload the DLL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do this in your main R session (without using RStudio, which makes reinstalling the package and reloading R very easy), you can use devtools:

```
library(devtools)
load_all("path/to/my/package")
```

Among other things, `load_all` will reload all your R code, and re-compile and reattach the DLL.

Answer (score 8):

Opinions are divided on this. I often prefer to run the builds and test outside of my main R session(s), simply by chaining `R CMD INSTALL` with `Rscript` (or, on Linux, `r` calls from littler) to test the new build.  If you use proper options to `R CMD INSTALL ...` to skip parts that may take extra time you get a quick turnaround AND are assured that you do get a fresh build.

And if you want the same behaviour by clicking a button, RStudio offers it too.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you need to run `library.dynam.unload` to unload DLLs.