# Error: Maximal number of DLLs reached

Tags: r, dll, package

I'm writing an R package which depends upon many other packages. When I load too many packages into the session I frequently got this error:

```
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/proxy/libs/proxy.so':
  `maximal number of DLLs reached...
```

This post [Exceeded maximum number of DLLs in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24832030/exceeded-maximum-number-of-dlls-in-r) pointed out that the issue is with the Rdynload.c of the base R code:
`#define MAX_NUM_DLLS 100`

Is there any way to bypass this issue except modifying and building from source?

Comment: Have you tried to use Microsoft R? I'm not sure that'll work, but it may be a viable alternative.

Comment: I just checked the source code of Microsoft R. I don't think they changed the '#define MAX_NUM_DLLS 100' code. Also some packages which require compilation cannot be installed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Increasing that number is of course "possible"... but it also costs a bit
(adding to the fixed memory footprint of R).

I did not set that limit, but I'm pretty sure it was also meant as reminder for the useR to "clean up" a bit in her / his R session, i.e., not load package namespaces unnecessarily.  I cannot yet imagine that you need > 100 packages | namespaces loaded in your R session.
OTOH, some packages nowadays have a host of dependencies, so I agree that this at least may happen accidentally more frequently than in the past.

The real solution of course would be a code improvement that starts with a relatively small number of "DLLinfo" structures (say 32), and then allocates more batches (of size say 32) if needed.

Patches to the R sources (development trunk in subversion at https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/ )  are very welcome!

----  added Jan.26, 2017:  In the mean time, we've had a [public bug report](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17202) about this, a proposed patch (which was not good enough: There is always an OS dependent limit on the number of open files), and today that bug report has been closed by R core member @TomasKalibera  who implemented new code where the maximal number of loaded DLLs is set at

> `pmax(100, pmin(1000, 0.6* OS_dependent_getrlimit_or_equivalent()))`

and so on Windows and Linux (and not yet tested, but "almost surely" macOS), the limit should be considerably higher than previously.

----- Update #2 (written Jan.5, 2018):
  In Oct'17, the above change was made more automatic with the following commit to the sources (of the development version of R - only!)

> r73545 | kalibera | 2017-10-12 14:41:20
>
> Increase the number of DLLs that can be loaded by default. If needed,
>   increase the soft limit on open files.

and on the help page `?dyn.load` (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/dynload.html) the  `ulimit -n <num_open_files>` is now mentioned (section **Note** close to bottom).

So you might consider using R's development version till that becomes "main stream" in April.
Alternatively, you do (in a terminal / shell)

> ulimit -n 2048

and then start R from that terminal. Tomas Kalibera mentioned this to work on macOS.

Comment: would the R Core team be open to bumping MAX_NUM_DLLS to 200 or so? Or is there more than meets the eye here? I'm working on the R package mlr and we run into this problem when performing unit tests for all the learners

Comment: Yes, there's slightly more.. see the threads on the R-devel mailing list, see e.g. my recent post https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2016-December/073529.html  (and messages around it).  I hope we have something by R 3.4.0 ca April'17 (and quite a bit sooner if you are willing to work with the development version of R.

Comment: Have the same problem here - was coding a package with a lot of dependencies, and I am now also getting this error...

Comment: @MartinMächler: was this then added to R 3.4.0?

Comment: Yes, it was added to R 3.4.0 --- however not quite as above.  It was found / that the above was still "too dangerous" / not okay in some cases, namely when the number of open files is limited (and it typically is limited quite a bit on (some?) Linux (such as my Fedora 24) and so R 3.4.0 now takes the default from an environment variable `R_MAX_NUM_DLLS` (which on Linux cannot be larger than 1000).     E.g. on my current (quite strong) desktop:

Comment: @MartinMächler: Thanks for your answer. It seems in MacOS system the maximum DLL number can only reach 153 otherwise R will report fatal error. Do you know if there is anyway to bypass this? Nowadays bioconductor packages generally have many dependences and could easily exhaust this limit.

Comment: @MartinMächler: Thanks for the update! That's awesome!

Answer (score 19):

As of R 3.4, you can set a different max number of DLLs using and environmental variable `R_MAX_NUM_DLLS`. From the release notes:

> The maximum number of DLLs that can be loaded into R e.g. *via*
>        dyn.load() can now be increased by setting the environment
>        variable R_MAX_NUM_DLLS before starting R.

Comment: To set this globally, should it be added to Renviron or Renviron.site?

Comment: See `?Startup`, or google gives multiple references describing startup configuration for R, e.g. [Understanding R's startup](https://rviews.rstudio.com/2017/04/19/r-for-enterprise-understanding-r-s-startup/)

Comment: from 'efficient R programming':  The .Renviron file is used to store system variables. It follows a similar start up routine to the .Rprofile file: R first looks for a global  .Renviron file, then for local versions. A typical use of the .Renviron file is to specify the R_LIBS path

Comment: On Windows there is an error when loading R is this environment variable is set to a value larger than 1000.

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue with the simpleSingleCell library in bioconductor

On the macOS you can't exceed 256. So I set my .Renviron in my home dir 
R_MAX_NUM_DLLS=150

Comment: Seems the actual limit on MacOS is 153 otherwise R 3.4 will throw fatal error.

Answer (score -2):

It's easy
Go to the environment variable and edit

```
variable_name = R_MAX_NUM_DLL
value = 1000
```

Restart R
worked well for me