# Error of prcomp in R

Tags: r, bioconductor

I am running a microarray data analysis,

```
raw_data = read.celfiles(....... )
exp_raw <- log2(exprs(raw_data)) 
PCA_raw <- prcomp(t(exp_raw), scale = FALSE)
```

and I got

```
Error in La.svd(x, nu, nv) : LAPACK routines cannot be loaded
Besides: Warning message:
In La.svd(x, nu, nv) :
   unable to load share-object'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//lapack.so' : `maximal number of DLLs reached...
```

this is the packages I loaded

```
library(Biobase, oligoClasses, knitr, BiocStyle, oligo, geneplotter, ggplot2, dplyr, LSD, gplots, RColorBrewer, ArrayExpress, arrayQualityMetrics, stringr, matrixStats, topGO, genefilter, pd.hugene.1.0.st.v1, hugene10sttranscriptcluster.db, pheatmap, mvtnorm, DAAG, multcomp, limma, ReactomePA, clusterProfiler, openxlsx, devtools, biomaRt, EnrichmentBrowser)
```

my session info

```
setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
 system   x86_64, darwin15.6.0        
 ui       RStudio (1.0.153)           
 language (EN)                        
 collate  zh_TW.UTF-8                 
 date     2017-10-03
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: As a possible work-around, separate your code into two scripts: one that loads, wrangles the data and then exports the result to an `.RData` file; and the second script that loads that `.RData` and performs PCA without also loading all the other unnecessary packages.

Comment: It works. But is it the DLL thinks? What if I changed the R environment to using R_MAX_NUM_DLLS ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Maximal number of DLLs reached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36974206/error-maximal-number-of-dlls-reached)