# Increase max number of DLLs in R Ubuntu from Rstudio

Tags: r, ubuntu, dll, r-environment

I kept getting the ``maximal number of DLLs reached...` error, but the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36974206/error-maximal-number-of-dlls-reached?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) didn't work for me from command line(this is OS dependent, I'm on Linux). Read on to see how I increased DLLs from within R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking around, and most solutions are very manual. I liked the editing method [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-set-a-variable-in-renviron/5029/3) We can fix this [from inside R](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-set-a-variable-in-renviron/5029/3):

```
install.packages("usethis")
usethis::edit_r_environ()
```

This will open up an editor for a newly created .Renviron file, where we write in:

```
R_MAX_NUM_DLLS=256
```

If you need more than this, you can increase it [based on operating system](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/dyn.load)

What this is doing is creating an .Renviron file in your home directory, and creating the R_MAX_NUM_DLLS environment variable, which will be 256 at this point. We can now load up to 256 rather than the default 100.

Comment: The answer is correct, but `usethis`  is a distraction. All you need is the `key=value` assignment in an `~/.Renviron` file (or one its alternatives).  Easiest done with an editor.

Comment: Morever, what you suggest here [is already said over there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43689526/143305) in several of the answers, so I will close this as duplicate.

Comment: This was for editing the R environment from Rstudio, rather than having to go to command line